# How to extract text which is similar to text in another cell from a column

Tags: crystal-reports

I have data in Excel that contains names and addresses of customers:

```
Name (col B)                                          Address (col d)
----------------------------------------------------  ----------------------------------------
"Lynette Hartsell 7329 Apple Mill, Efland, NC 27243"  "Lynette Hartsell 7329 Apple Mill,"
"Hart Crystal"                                        "David & Crystal Hart 2056 Garry Court,"
```

The addresses in Col D contains names too, along with the address.

Is there a way to extract the address only and get rid of the name from column D?

For example: It should return with "2056 Garry court" only and get rid of "David and crystal hart"

[image: snapshot of the data]

Comment: It seems to me like the simplest option would be to just remove all characters to the left of the first number that appears in column D since an address should always start with a number. Will that work?

Comment: Yes, that is what i want to do.. any formula that can help me do that for the entire data in one go?